# React trigger useEffect when two things changes

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use react hooks and I want to run a function when two things change:

```
const Filter = ({ orderList, orders }) => {
  const [from, setFrom] = useState();
  const [to, setTo] = useState();
  const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState(orders);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filteredOrders = orders.filter(function(item) {
      return item.order_number >= from && item.order_number <= to;
    });
    setFilteredList(filteredOrders);
    console.log(filteredList);
  }, [from, to]);
```

more precisely I would like to filter the array only when BOTH `from` and `to` states changes, this is because I am trying to filter an array from some inputs defined by the user.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't just add a `Filter` button and handle the filtering when the button is clicked? Without the button, it's quite confusing when the user needs to make changes to both to see the updated effect. With the button, if the user needs to change only 1 value to trigger the filtering, it's also possible

Answer (score 13):

You would not be able to accomplish this by passing in more arguments into `useEffect()`, by default that will cause `useEffect()` to execute as long as one item is changed.

You could however combine `useEffect` with `useRef` to accomplish this. We will use `useRef` to store the previous values of the states and compare that to our new state values.

See codesandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-nobel-6ece5

```
const App = () => {
  const [from, setFrom] = useState();
  const [to, setTo] = useState();

  const previousValues = useRef({ from, to });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      previousValues.current.from !== from &&
      previousValues.current.to !== to
    ) {
      //your logic here
      console.log("both changed")
      previousValues.current = { from, to };
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="from"
        value={from}
        onChange={e => setFrom(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="to"
        value={to}
        onChange={e => setTo(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -2):

For all other people looking for any answer. Found a easy method to do this.

Use two eperate useEffects with those two values changing.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const filteredOrders = orders.filter(function(item) {
      return item.order_number >= from && item.order_number <= to;
    });
    setFilteredList(filteredOrders);
    console.log(filteredList);
  }, [from]);


 useEffect(() => {
    const filteredOrders = orders.filter(function(item) {
      return item.order_number >= from && item.order_number <= to;
    });
    setFilteredList(filteredOrders);
    console.log(filteredList);
  }, [to]);
```

**Tried Chris Ngos solution. But it didn't work properly for me.
This one is working much better.**

Comment: This answers the question, "How to trigger when `a` OR `b` changes?"
The question here is "How to trigger when `a` AND `b` changes?"

Furthermore, this creates the same function twice, duplicating code and wasting computation; you should use a `useCallback()` to store functions that you intend to call.